# need an idea on getting user input(UI Design)

Tags: html, css, user-interface, web

In my application, i want to allow the user to input images at particular locations of their content/article, so that after editing and everything, when the article is finally published for viewing; the images are properly aligned and positioned at **proper and exact** places as if it was manually designed using some WYSIWYG editors by the user himself. So, I'm currently in brain-storming mode, to think of an  idea, about **how to get such an input from the user so that they can specify the location of those image with as much hassle as possible**??? Any **suggestion on how the UI** should be looking like and designed are most welcome.

Comment: Why don't you use a WYSIWYG editor itself?

Comment: Take a look at the CKEditor (right-click images for options): http://ckeditor.com/demo

Comment: hmmm, thanks for reminding. That's right I could definitely use an editor itself. Even thought now now, but, at some point of time I'll have to port the application to mobile with minimal javascript. So, if possible I'd try my best to avoid scripts usage as much as possible. For now, I'm just looking for new ideas for user input. Implementation of the UI(whatever is decided) is the next step.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Markdown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/) to format your text much like the Stack Overflow text editor. You specify images like: `![alt tag](link/to/image)`. That would give you pretty good control over where the images go in relation to the text.

If Markdown is too heavy for your needs you could always create some sort of tag that people can use in the editor.